# Unable to write particular regular expression in R language

Tags: regex, r, machine-learning

```
string1<-"ccjar_neutral v_neutral vaux_neutral nnp_neutral prn_neutral v_neutral inj_neutral"
```

How to write regular expression to

1. Extract only "v_neutral" from string1
2. Extract "v_neutral vaux_neutral" from string1

Comment: is there any logic behind this?

Comment: Do you need one regex, or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess...

```
str_extract_all(string1, "\\b(v\\w+)(?:\\s+v\\w+)\\b")[[1]]
# [1] "v_neutral vaux_neutral"
str_extract_all(string1, "\\b(v\\w+)(?=\\s+v\\w+)\\b")[[1]]
# [1] "v_neutral"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Can you please suggest me any tutorial that will guide me to write regular expressions?

Comment: i learned all the stuffs from this site only. You may consider reading regex-info.com

Comment: In above example,If i want to write a pattern in grep() function what should be the pattern?

Comment: grep? ask it as a new question with description.